# Cannot get my head around this basic algorithm involving a simple for-loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, algorithm, for-loop

Consider a string whose first letter is always `"M"` and whose other characters can be pretty much any combinations of `"I"s` and `"U"s` (no other letter allowed, just `Is` and `Us`). For example: `MIU`, `MUI`, `MIUIU`, `MUIIUIU`, `MUIIIUIIIUIII`, `MIUUIUIIIUUI` are all strings of this kind.

I want a function that given any such string as input, returns an array with all the possible ways the pattern `"III"` can, if it appears at all in the input string, be replaced with `"U"` in the input. For example, there are 2 ways `"III"` can be replaced with `"U"` in `"MIIII"`, namely `MUI` and `MIU`. Therefore, the function should, given `MIIII` as input, return `[MUI, MIU]`.

This is my (flawed) function. The idea behind it is that of looping through the input string (i.e. `MIstring`) looking for `"III"`. Each time `"III"` is found, `MIstring` is added to the `IIIoptions` array but with `"U"` replacing `"III"`.

```
function ruleThree() {
    var IIIoptions = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < MIstring.length; i++) {
        if (MIstring.slice(i, i+3) === "III") {          
           IIIoptions.push(MIstring.replace(MIstring.slice(i, i+3), "U"));
        }
    }
    return IIIoptions;
}
```

Given the input `MIIII`, I expected the function to return `[MUI, MIU]`. However, it returns `[MUI, MUI]`. I have tried with different inputs and it displays the same problem, that is, all the items in the array are the same. For example, given the string `MIIIIUIIIIU` it gives me `[MUIUIIIIU, MUIUIIIIU, MUIUIIIIU, MUIUIIIIU]` instead of `[MUIUIIIIU, MIUUIIIIU, MIIIIUUIU, MIIIIUIUU]`. So the function gets the number of `"III"s` contained in MIstring right, but it does not return the array that I would expect it to return.

What is wrong with my function?

Comment: This is because your `.replace` always replaces _the first_ `III` -- no matter what the actual position is. What you need is `result.push(slice-before-the-position + U + slice-after-the-position)` instead of `replace`.

Comment: Or, if you don't need to use a `for()` loop, use `reduce()` and avoid the side-effect nature of your code.

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-all-possible-combinations-of-r-elements-in-a-given-array-of-size-n/

Comment: Thank you all for your answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is that you are using [String.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) and that method will always replace the first matching sequence of `III` by `U` the way you are calling it. You can use [String.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) to generate the new string with the replacement when a match is found, like this:

```js
const input = "MIIIII";

function ruleThree(str)
{
    var IIIoptions = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++)
    {
        if (str.slice(i, i + 3) === "III")
           IIIoptions.push(str.slice(0, i) + "U" + str.slice(i + 3));
    }
    
    return IIIoptions;
}

console.log(ruleThree(input));
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

However, note the previous approach will fail if you need more than one replacement at a time, for example, if your input is `MIIIIII` it will not generate the `MUU` string. In this case, you will have to use a recursive way:

```js
const input = "MIIIIIII";

function getCombs(str, res = new Set())
{
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++)
    {
        if (str.slice(i, i + 3) === "III")
        {
           let r = str.slice(0, i) + "U" + str.slice(i + 3);
           res.add(r);
           getCombs(r, res);
        }
    }

    return [...res];
}

console.log(getCombs(input));
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```